# Custom 22.04 Server iso results in "unable to find a medium containing a live file system"

Tags: boot, server, grub2, 22.04, iso

I was trying to make a custom 22.04 iso that would auto install with cloud init. However after getting past grub the initramfs would not be able to find the filesystem. I thought to remove my cloudinit and custom changes from the image to see if they were causing the issue, but I can easily replicate it without making any changes to a standard 22.04 server image:

```
# Extract the contents of the official iso
7z -y x ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso -osource-files 
mv source-files/\[BOOT\]/ BOOT  # take out the mbr and efi from the image
# Build new iso from old iso
sudo xorriso -outdev Custom.iso \
  -map source-files / -- -volid "Shield 1.1 Ubuntu Remix amd64" \
  -boot_image grub grub2_mbr=BOOT/1-Boot-NoEmul.img \
  -boot_image any partition_table=on \
  -boot_image any partition_cyl_align=off \
  -boot_image any partition_offset=16 \
  -boot_image any mbr_force_bootable=on -append_partition 2 28732ac11ff8d211ba4b00a0c93ec93b BOOT/2-Boot-NoEmul.img \
  -boot_image any appended_part_as=gpt \
  -boot_image any iso_mbr_part_type=a2a0d0ebe5b9334487c068b6b72699c7 \
  -boot_image any cat_path='/boot.catalog' \
  -boot_image grub bin_path='/boot/grub/i386-pc/eltorito.img' \
  -boot_image any platform_id=0x00 \
  -boot_image any emul_type=no_emulation \
  -boot_image any load_size=2048 \
  -boot_image any boot_info_table=on \
  -boot_image grub grub2_boot_info=on \
  -boot_image any next \
  -boot_image any efi_path=--interval:appended_partition_2:all:: \
  -boot_image any platform_id=0xef \
  -boot_image any emul_type=no_emulation \
  -boot_image any load_size=4349952
```

I followed the guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Creating_the_ISO_Image

I also read in the section above that you need to update the md5sum, so I have attempted that too but with similar results.

Any ideas why the file system is not being detected?

Comment: For anyone that is having this problem in the future, I found this repo online from another post: https://github.com/YasuhiroABE/ub2204-autoinstall-iso.git

For reasons I don't understand, this appears to work exactly how I want it to. I don't understand specifically what is different from my original setup, but now that I have something that works i'm hoping that I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the issue, although I don't fully understand what exactly is causing the issue.

After mounting the ubuntu iso file, I `cp` the files out of the directory into my own directory in which I would build the iso. For reasons I don't understand, this `cp` is the cause of the issue.

Instead, you have to `rsync -av` and that will result in a working image. I'm not sure what specifically is different about `cp` and `rsync`, but hopefully this helps someone in the future.